# ¿Como borrar imagen de base de datos mysql y hacer que se borre de la carpeta donde se guardo?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, base-de-datos

Lo que quiero hez hacer que la extencion que se guarda en la base de datos se borre pero tambien se borre la imagen de la carpeta donde se guardo

Comment: Hola @ivanrangel, edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve]. Si no tienes idea de como empezar, divide tu pregunta en partes más pequeñas y manejables. Primero averigua como eliminar un registro, luego como borrar un archivo; luego envuelve ambas operaciones en una función a la que le pases un parámetro. Usa Google para tu búsqueda. Recuerda que en este sitio se deben mostrar problemas específicos y puntuales de programación.

Comment: es lo mas claro que lo pude dejar solo quiero que al eliminar un registro en donde se encuentra almacenada la extencion y el nombre de la imagen de la base de datos y que se borre la imagen de la carpeta donde se encuentra almacenada solo quiero eso saber como borrar la imagen del directorio en donde se encuentra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes eliminar la imagen en el directorio donde se encuentra después o antes (como prefieras, considerando que después debes tener almacenado en alguna variable su ubicación) de borrar su registro de la base de datos con funciones propias de PHP. ¿Haz investigado acerca de como eliminar ficheros de un directorio con PHP?. Existen varios ejemplos en la web te dejo uno:

```
  $dir = "/directorio/"; /*Ruta local donde se almacenan tu imagen*/
  $file = "imagen.jpg"; /* Nombre de tu imagen */
  unlink($dir.$file);  /* Eliminas tu Imagen*/
```

Esto basándome en las etiquetas que ingresaste en la pregunta. Saludos espero te sirva.

Comment: #Samuel Heredia. Excelentísimo tu si me entiendes y muchisimas gracias le diste en el clavo